# Periodically change Desktop wallpapers automatically on different displays independently

Tags: macos, wallpaper

I am running macOS Catalina with dual screens.

Is there a way to display a different macOS wallpaper on each screen that also cycles through all the macOS wallpapers?

Comment: Did you notice the `Change picture:` checkbox towards the bottom of the Desktop & Screen Saver preference pane under System Preferences app? It is meant to perform exactly the feature you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @NimeshNeema, that option is greyed out for me.

Comment: I found I had to select the photos in the 2nd section on the right, however the first 2 or 3 photos didn't work, I had to move down to the 2nd or 3rd row in this section, then the `change picture` & `random order` became selectable. Add an answer if you like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacOS Mojave: Can not make changing background wallpaper](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367969/macos-mojave-can-not-make-changing-background-wallpaper)

Comment: @ankii - The OP is asking how to **display a different wallpaper on each of the displays** connected to the Mac, not how to configure rotating backgrounds.  By default, even with rotating wallpapers, it’s *the same* for all connected displays

Comment: See if this works for you.... https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/216759/119271

Comment: @Allan they said that the option is greyed out, which needs shifting focus...

Comment: Still irrelevant, @ankii  the question is very different in that it's getting different wallpapers on independent displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a feature built into macOS that lets you do this. Go to System Preferences app → Desktop & Screen Saver and click to select the Desktop tab.

[image]

You'd see a **Change picture:** checkbox towards the bottom. Enabling it would let you setup automatic change of wallpaper at a configurable duration.

[image]

Comment: I find that in macOS 12 the second desktop disables the change setting after some hours. Both screens have the same source folder.