# macOS desktop pictures can't change automatically

Tags: macos, wallpaper

macOS Monterey 12.2.

I'd like my desktop background to cycle through macOS Desktop Pictures automatically every x period, e.g. every 1 minute.

From [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382699/5076), the `Change picture` setting is greyed out:

[image]

How can I get Desktop Pictures to `Change picture` automatically?

If I select the parent of Desktop Pictures, Apple, I get random Colours also, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I have different **Spaces** set up for my Desktops. I set **System Preferences** to be shown on **All Desktops** by right clicking on **System Pref's icon** in the **Dock** and selecting --> **Options/Assign To All Desktops**

When my **Change picture** setting is greyed out in **System Preferences**, as you described, for some unknown reason if I switch to a different **Space** then back to the previous **Space** again... the **Change picture** setting is no longer greyed out.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the `Options/Assign To All Desktops` option when right-clicking the System Preferences icon in the Dock. If I press `CTRL + up-arrow`, then `CTRL + right-arrow` to switch to Desktop 2, nothing happens, so `Change picture` is still greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer, the question regards Right-Click on Desktop > Apple > Desktop Pictures. Unable to select Change picture / Random order. It will work on Colors.

ALL of the island/rock/land/sea and other desktop images are buried in XML Code.

As far as I know, there is only one way to get the PREFERRED  images to change automatically. Here is the workaround.

The objective of the following steps is to minimize and eliminate EVERYTHING on the desktop, except for the single folder you create.

Move any folders & files on the desktop to your HD/SSD/External Drive. Create a single MT desktop folder and name with a single character. Go to FINDER PREFERENCES > General > DESELECT any of the Check Marked 1st four items.

Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar > Slide Dock Size to small. Next, Menu Bar > Check both Options.

Right-Click Desktop and IF HIDE VIEW OPTIONS is visible,, CLICK IT TO ENABLE: Show View Options. Change Icon Size to 16 X 16. Grid spacing MINIMAL; Text size 10; Label Position BOTTOM; UNCHECK Show Item Info & Show Icon Preview. The Desktop should have a single TINY Folder. Hide it in a corner or wherever you'd like to. You are now prepared for Phase 2.

Using Desktop & Screen Saver > Apple > Desktop Pictures. Choose the ones you want. Start by choosing a single image and letting it display - full size - on your desktop. Click Shift > Command > 4 to activate the screen capture tool. Select the maximum image area that contains NOTHING unrelated on the desktop. Pick a point in Far-Left Top Corner, avoiding any toolbar image near top that is visible. Scroll to Far-Right Bottom Corner and stop before the dock and your tiny file folder. Click to select and the screen image is now on your desktop. Name it, and move it to the TINY folder. Repeat for each chosen image. Once you've captured the desired images, go back to Desktop & Screen Saver. Under Albums, create a subdirectory named Desktop System Photos (or whatever) and move the photos from your tiny desktop folder to the DSP folder.

Select that directory and CHECK Change Picture then select time between photos. Of course, Random order is another choice.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Ventura (probably Monterey too) you can:

1. Download the Desktop Picture you want by clicking in their cloud icon (notice how I didn't download the 4 in the bottom row and they still show the icons):

[image]

2. Select Auto-Rotate and browse to `/Users/{your_username}/Library/Application Support/com.apple.mobileAssetDesktop` where the photos were downloaded:

[image]